# A pyramid of numbers starting with 0 ending with 9

Tags: java

I would like to print a pyramid of numbers starting with 0 and ending with 9, when it equal 9, program should start over again from 0 to 9 and so on...

Here is what I have tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j += 2) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print(" " + k);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

which printed

```
      0
     0 1 2
    0 1 2 3 4
   0 1 2 3 4 5 6
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

but I need this..

```
            0
         1  2  3
      4  5  6  7  8
   9  0  1  2  3  4  5...
```

Comment: And what is what you get?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wprNW.png i get this..

Comment: Hint : Why do you always print k from 0?

Comment: Idk.. Help me with the answer

Comment: You could just keep a counter for your numbers and print `counter % 10`, i.e. you start with 0 and keep incrementing (don't reset that counter!). You also probably don't want to increment `j` by 2 since that's why you are printing less blanks than needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing `k` which starts from `0` for every iteration of `i` printing `0 1 2 3..` everytime. Instead create a local variable initialized to `0` and print it and also increase it by one everytime. In your case you want to start the counter from `0` when `counter` value is greater than `9` you can add a check for that by including `if(counter > 9) counter = 0;`. Added a code below:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
 for (int j = 0; j < 20 - i; j++) {
  System.out.print(" ");
 }
 for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
  System.out.print(" " + counter++);
  if(counter > 9) counter = 0;
 }

 System.out.println();
}
```

Output

```
             0
           1 2 3
         4 5 6 7 8
       9 0 1 2 3 4 5
     6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4
```

[**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/IEkT2a)

Comment: Why `j < 20`? That would just indent the pyramid and might not be wanted. Also instead of the if to increase the counter you could just do `System.out.print(" " + (counter++ % 10));`.

Comment: Good work (NOT).  Now he can just copy your code and miss out on the learning experience of debugging his own code.

Comment: @Thomas yes `j<20` is optional I added it for extra spacing. I posted the code which came into my mind first but thanks for the other solution.

Comment: @StephenC being member of SO for more than a year I know that we should avoid adding answer to researchless questions. But the OP posted the tried code so thats why I posted my answer.

Comment: I'd the the problem is not that you answered the question but that you just posted some code. In order to help the OP learn something from your answer should should add an explanation of what you changed/are doing and why (i.e. how it works). That way the OP and others who read this should be enabled to adapt the learnings to different problems.

Comment: @Thomas thanks updated my answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable and increment it every time.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10 - i; j += 2) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) {
            System.out.print(" " + count++);
            if(count>9)
                count=count%10;
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
```